# Where to change colors of the Cursor and the Current Line?

Tags: phpstorm

I have set up a dark color layout. Yet I cannot seem to find two things:

Where to set the

1. background color of the current line?
2. color of the cursor?

I suppose the settings must be somewhere in `Colors & Fonts`, either in `General` or `Php` , yet I am searching them wrong.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For the cursor color (or "Caret") go to:

`Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Caret`

For the current line backround (or "Caret Row") go to:

`Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Caret Row`

---

PHPStorm on Windows

[image: Caret]

[image: Caret row]

---

On OS X (PHPStorm 7)

[image: Caret Row PHPStorm on OS X]

Comment: Really, "caret" is what I was supposed to search? Narf! And thanks :)

Comment: Caret? Why not just name it `cursor` and `highlight current line`?

Comment: I spent ages looking for how to disable highlighting for current line did realise it was hidden here. +1

Comment: This setting is called "Highlight Current Line" in the ReSharper tool. I grant them no excuse - no doubt they felt obliged to keep the name consistent with another or older product... but the name "caret row" is absolutely unfindable

Comment: Please note that in Oracle's SQL Developer is the same story. 
to change cursor color go to 
Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Caret Behavior -> Caret Color

Comment: Update: current version adds a level of organization, so once you went to `Editor > Colors & Fonts > General`, then find `Caret` and `Caret row` under `Editor` (tested on WebStorm 2016.3.5 )

Comment: Note this only changes the color of the blinking caret, it does not change the color of the mouse cursor (I-bar). So the mouse cursor is still difficult to see on dark background.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version:

Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Editor -> Caret row

[image]